# Events only firing if I place a Console.WriteLine in a Getter

Tags: c#, events, task

Ok. I know that I should not fire an Event inside a Getter, but I'm drafting code in LinqPad and Dotnetfiddle, so I want to be concise, and not create another method.

I have a loop routine that:

```
            await Task.Run(() 
            => RepeatAction.Every(() =>
                 {
                     if (!this.AllCyclesEnded || NumberOfSteps == 1)
                     {
                         if (NumberOfSteps > 1) ++Counter;
                         var tidalVolume = 500; var plateauPressure = SimulatePlateauAdjustment(12f, this.CurrentPEEP);
                         //var plateauPressure = 29;
                         var thisCycle = MeasurementCycle.Creator(this.CurrentPEEP, tidalVolume, plateauPressure);
                         if (!IsIdealPEEP)
                             CycleIterator(thisCycle);
                     }
                 },
                 TimeSpan.FromSeconds(StepDuration), cancellation.Token).Wait()
            , abortedCyclesBecauseIdealPEEPFound.Token);
```

And depending of some things that **CycleIterator(thisCycle);** does, it fires some Events:

```
public bool AllCyclesEnded
{
    get
    {
        if (HaveAllCyclesEnded && !CyclesEndedEventFired)
        {
            CyclesEndedEventFired = true;
            OnCycleEnded(new CycleEndedEventArgs(Cycle.Count > 0 ? Cycle.LastOrDefault() : default
                                , this.Counter, this.CurrentPEEP, this.EndPEEP
                                , this.AllCyclesEnded, this.CyclePhase));
            Console.WriteLine($"\t\tEnded @ {this.Counter} loops with currentPEEP of {this.CurrentPEEP} in {this.CyclePhase} phase.");
            //Without above, neither of these events fire...
            OnCyclesEnded(new CyclesEndedEventArgs(Cycle.Count > 0 ? Cycle.LastOrDefault() : default
                                , this.Counter, this.CurrentPEEP, this.EndPEEP, this.CyclePhase));              
        }
        return HaveAllCyclesEnded;      
    }
}
```

This piece of code above only fires IF I left the Console.WriteLine there; if not, Getter is called (AllCyclesEnded == true), but Events are not Fired...
Any hints?

EDIT2: Console.WriteLine solve the problem in a non deterministically way; about 60% of runs...

EDIT1 after Charlieface comments; it is a Task that returns an Action:

```
public static class RepeatAction
{
    public static async Task Every(Action action,
        TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            action();
            Task task = Task.Delay(interval, cancellationToken);
            try
            {
                await task;
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a threading issue: `Console.WriteLine` takes a lock, which forces a full memory barrier. Without that, reading from `CyclesEndedEventFired` might not return the most up to date value

Comment: Any suggestion how to solve, or investigate it? Maybe using Visual Studio will be easier to spot the problem?

Comment: Are you reading any variables from different threads without any locking mechanism? I see you have `await Task.Run` do you ever do `Task.Run` without `await`?

Comment: @Charlieface, you are right... `RepeatAction.Every(()` is a Task... but I'm Waiting for it `).Wait()`

Comment: In fact, RepeatAction is a Task returning an Action... I'll show on Edit1:

Comment: Now, seeing where the cats is, I'll try do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191791/c-sharp-async-within-an-action)