# Action is async or not?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, action

Lets suppose we have an action execution wrapper like this:

```
private void ExecuteAction(Action action)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"starting action ...");
    action();
    Console.WriteLine($"finished action ...");
}
```

Lets suppose we call it like this:

```
ExecuteAction( async () => { ... } ); // 1
```

or like this:

```
ExecuteAction( () => { ... } ); // 2
```

I wonder what is the difference between the two call and how to handle inside the `ExecuteAction()` method? Is there any difference?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to handle"? Do you want to differentiate between the two? I don't think you can.

Comment: The difference is, that _async_ keyword makes the lambda function asynchronous. It allows you to use the _await_ keyword within that function.

Comment: That would translate to `async void` which (with exceptions) is a well- known anti pattern. You may prefer `Func<Task>` to make it awaitable.

Comment: @Musti that's a common misconception. `async` doesn't make it asynchronous. It still could be executed synchronously.

Comment: @Fildor that's true, should've better expressed it as "allows it to be executed async".

Comment: Looks to me like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191791/c-sharp-async-within-an-action

Comment: Thats nonsense... it says do not use Action anymore, Funct<Task> must use, because we do not know if the caller calls the method async () => way or () => way?

Comment: Action is inherently not awaitable. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: And that being said: nothing stops you to offer both. One for synchronous api, one for potentially asynchronous api.

Comment: @Musti You weren't wrong, though, since even MSDN defines the language to be used in that context as : _"If you use this modifier on a method or expression, it's referred to as an async method."_ - which I find really confusing at times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use an `Action` delegate here would translate to `async void` which is a [well-known anti-pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) (with exceptions).

See, the `async` keyword is not part of the signature. It is an implementation detail, that allows the use of `await` inside the method.

So, for `ExecuteAction` it does not make a difference. All it sees is a `void Action()` delegate. And using it like `ExecuteAction( async () => { await SomethingAsync(); });` comes with all the pitfalls and downsides layed out in the article, I linked above. (tl;dr: *really* not recommended to do)

See also docs on the keyword itself:

> void. async void methods are generally discouraged for code other than event handlers because callers cannot await those methods and must implement a different mechanism to report successful completion or error conditions.

- [async - C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async#return-types)

If you want to offer both sync and async experiences to your audience, you could do something like:

```
// your already known implementation
private void ExecuteAction(Action action)
{
  // ...
}

/// <summary>Async Version</summary>
/// <example>
/// Usage:
/// <code>
/// await ExecuteAsync( () => { ... } );
/// </code>
/// or
/// <code>
/// await ExecuteAsync( async () => { ... await SomethingAsync(); ... } );
/// </code>
/// </example>
private async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> asyncAction)
{
    // Before client-defined function code goes here
    await asyncAction();
    // After client-defined function code goes here
}
```

If you need to, you can also pass a state object and avoid it being captured:

```
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// await ExecuteAsync( o => { ... }, someStateObject );
/// </code>
/// </example>
private async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<object,Task> asyncAction, object state = null)
{
    await asyncAction(state);
}
```

Providing async API, I'd also always give the opportunity to pass a [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-8.0):

```
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// await ExecuteAsync( o => { ... }, someStateObject, cancel );
/// </code>
/// </example>
private async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<object, CancellationToken, Task> asyncAction, object state = null, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    await asyncAction(state, token);
}
```

If this is GUI-related, you may also consider reporting progress:

```
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// await ExecuteAsync( o => { ... }, someStateObject, p => { ... },cancel );
/// </code>
/// </example>
private async Task ExecuteAsync<TProgress>(
     Func<object, IProgress<TProgress>, CancellationToken, Task> asyncAction,
     object state = null, 
     IProgress<TProgress> progress = null,
     CancellationToken token = default)
{
    await asyncAction(state, progress, token);
}
```

And of course you can make your state object type-safe

```
private async Task ExecuteAsync<TState, TProgress>(
     Func<TState, IProgress<TProgress>, CancellationToken, Task> asyncAction,
     TState state = null, 
     IProgress<TProgress> progress = null,
     CancellationToken token = default)
{
    await asyncAction(state, progress, token);
}
```

---

Sources:

[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming # Avoid Async Void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) - Stephen Cleary, March 2013, MSDN Magazine

[async - C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async#return-types)

Comment: Thank for the very detailed answer! But I lost somewhere... so you suggest not to write `async () => ` or you suggesting create to different `ExecuteAction()` implementations: one for a non-async actions, and one for the async ones?

Comment: Exactly. You just have to name them differently, because they have different return types. But, yes: Have one thing for Sync and one thing for Async.