# Webview2 multithreading freezes/stops

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, webview2

I've been working on a fun side project. Basically I simulate two incognito browsers with `Webview2`. They go to persons X Instagram profile list and start liking stories of followers. I want both to execute async Javascript code at the same time. So I use multithreading. Every `Webview2` browser gets a thread. The problem is that when both `Webview2` instances start one instance keeps running the script-loop `Method4`. But it seems that the other instance runs this method for like a few seconds and freezes/stops? It's kinda weird and I don't really know what's happening. I might be overlooking something but I really can't figure it out.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();
    tabPage.Name = "tabPage" + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1);
    tabPage.Text = "tabPage" + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1);
    tabPage.Margin = tabControl1.TabPages[0].Margin;
    tabPage.Padding = tabControl1.TabPages[0].Padding;
    tabPage.Size = tabControl1.TabPages[0].Size;

    CustomBrowser customBrowser = new CustomBrowser(this);
    bool done = await customBrowser.InitBrowser();

    tabPage.Controls.Add(customBrowser.webView2);

    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);

    string name = names[0];
    names.RemoveAt(0);

    Thread browserThread = new Thread(async () =>
    {
        Method4(customBrowser, name);
    });

    threads.Add(browserThread);
}
```

First I create a new tab with an instance of `Webview2` (`CustomBrowser` class does all of the initializing for the `Webview2` instance). And after that I create and define a thread and it to a list.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Thread browserThread in threads)
    {
        browserThread.Start();
    }
}
```

After I created two tabs with two browsers I start all threads with the code from above. Both threads will now start executing `Method4` which is:

```
private async void Method4(CustomBrowser customBrowser, string scrape)
{
    while (!customBrowser.BrowserStopped)
    {
        customBrowser.webView2.Invoke(new Action(async () =>
        {
            customBrowser.webView2.CoreWebView2.Navigate($"https://www.instagram.com/{scrape}/followers/");
        }));

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        //Select follower box
        customBrowser.webView2.Invoke(new Action(async () =>
        {
            await customBrowser.webView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"var box = document.querySelectorAll('div._aano');");
        }));  

        int index = 0;
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int increment = 500;
        while (index < 100)
        {
            customBrowser.webView2.Invoke(new Action(async () =>
            {
                await customBrowser.webView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"box[0].scrollTop = {increment};");
                index = int.Parse(await customBrowser.webView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelectorAll('div._aarf._aarg').length;")) - 1;
            }));

            // Get names from lastIndex to index
            if (index > lastIndex)
            {
                for (int i = lastIndex + 1; i <= index; i++)
                {
                    // Click profile picture
                    customBrowser.webView2.Invoke(new Action(async () =>
                    {
                        await customBrowser.webView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"var profile = document.querySelectorAll('div._aarf._aarg')[{i}]; profile.scrollIntoView();");
                    }));
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(1521, 3526)));
                    customBrowser.webView2.Invoke(new Action(async () =>
                    {
                        await customBrowser.webView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"profile.click();");
                    }));
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(3000, 4567)));
                    // Like story
                    customBrowser.webView2.Invoke(new Action(async () =>
                    {
                        string response = await customBrowser.webView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("var likeButton = document.querySelector('span.x1i64zmx'); if (likeButton.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].getAttribute('aria-label') === 'Vind ik leuk') { likeButton.children[0].click(); }");
                    }));
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(1000, 2000)));
                    // Exit story
                    customBrowser.webView2.Invoke(new Action(async () =>
                    {
                        await customBrowser.webView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('div.xjbqb8w.x1ypdohk.xw7yly9.xktsk01.x1yztbdb.x1d52u69.x10l6tqk.x13vifvy.xds687c').children[0].click();");
                    }));
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(1521, 3526)));
                }
                lastIndex = index;
            }

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(1, 3)));
            increment += random.Next(500, 800);
        }

        customBrowser.BrowserStopped = true;
    }
}
```

This method basically like 100 Instagram stories and that's it. So that's basically all the code. One thread and one browser successfully perform `Method4` and keep doing this. But the second thread only seems to be working for the first few lines of `Method4` (navigating and opening follower list) and then stops working. How is this possible? I just want to simulate two independent incognito browsers and run scripts on them. Just as if I were to open two Chrome browsers.

Comment: For starters, remove any Thread and all *invokations*. You can try with a List<Task>, add your `Method4`(s), changed in `private async Task Method4()` to the List, and `await Task.WhenAll([Your List of Tasks])`

Comment: I'm, not sure whether instances of WebView2 can work concurrently in this manner because I've tested it like that. But it can work concurrently in the GUI

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for your response. I changed everything to Tasks. I removed the invokations but I now get the errors : "System.InvalidOperationException: 'CoreWebView2 can only be accessed from the UI thread.'" I guess that's why I added them in the first place. What do you recommend me in achieving what I want? Is it even possible with Webview2?

Comment: If you have used `Task.Run()`, remove that, too. I'm going to test the functionality of WebView2, in this context, when I have some time

Comment: @Jimi Alright thanks for your answer. I did everything you've said and using await Task.WhenAll in the button2_click method but it's just doing nothing. Method4 is never called when im debugging. I am probs doing something wrong.

Comment: @Jimi Alright never mind got it working the way you described but it didn't the behaviour is still the same for the different tasks

Comment: Somewhat related: [Parallel using of WebView2 in async Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66394112/parallel-using-of-webview2-in-async-task).

Comment: FYI using an [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void "Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming - Avoid Async Void") delegate in a `Thread` constructor [is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364092/is-it-ok-to-use-async-with-a-threadstart-method "Is it ok to use "async" with a ThreadStart method?").

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I tried implementing "TaskRunSTA" from the link you posted here but that results in "System.InvalidOperationException: 'CoreWebView2 can only be accessed from the UI thread.'"

Comment: This is correct. All UI controls are thread-affine. They expect that they'll be accessed by one thread only, and this thread will be a STA thread. So you must be very careful to respect this rule. To be honest I don't know how you can place two controls in different tabs of the same `Form`, and run them on separate STA threads. I would say it's not possible. It's only possible if you place them in separate forms.

Comment: *`new Action(async () =>`* -- This is [problematic too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191791/c-sharp-async-within-an-action "C# async within an action"). The delegate is `async void`, which is not what you want.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Alright. So instead of creating a new tab with another instance of webview2 it would be better just to create another form instance with a webview2 component and run the "Method4" in this form to achieve 2 browsers both running javascipt etc.?

Comment: Gerrit yes, opening two forms on two separate STA threads would be my second suggestion. My first suggestion would be to stick with a single thread, if you can. Multithreading is difficult.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks for your expertise, it's really appreciated. But the entire point of this fun project was implementing webview2 with multithreading, multiple browsers, multiple loops, etc. So I think im going with summoning multiple forms.

Comment: In case you come up with a solution, and no one has posted a good-enough answer, you could consider posting a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with your findings.

Comment: BTW, you're adding those Controls to TabPages. Is that because you need to see what happens after the scripts are executed? In any case, the operations of a WebView2 Control are already asynchronous (both awaitable methods and event callbacks), you can just set the Source and everything else is executed asynchronously. Or are you actually trying to use it as a head-less browser, which doesn't need to show an interface, just perform some actions in the background? -- Looking at your code again, it doesn't appear you need any Tasks or Threads at all

Comment: @Jimi No i really need multiple instances because on each instance i login to instagram and I want each instance to perform its own async while loop with javascript logic

Comment: What did I say? One instance of a WebView Control per TabPage (or one class instance, if no GUI is required). Each instance subscribes to its own events using its own event handlers. No need to execute a list of Tasks or starting Threads (which is not needed and really counter-productive). Unless is that `customBrowser` thing that creates a problem